# Dialog extending from AlertBuilder?

Tags: android

Is there a way to use my own Dialog-extended class with an AlertBuilder style? Right now I have:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    switch (id) {
        case MY_DIALOG:
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dlg_layout, null);

            AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(view)
                .create();
            return dlg;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But it's getting too crazy, and I'd like to move the dialog definition into its own class. (the above doesn't look too bad, I'm skipping a lot for the sake of clarity - basically I'm using a somewhat complicated custom view with AlertBuilder).

I very much want to use Dialog Fragment, but am not ready to do it yet, I need to build this as a temporary thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use my own Dialog-extended class with an
>   AlertBuilder style

```
class MyClass extends AlertDialog.Builder{
            . . .
}
```